# is there any difference between phonegap and cordova commands?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I just installed Phonegap for the first time.confuses me is the fact that some docs are using the command "phonegap" and some "cordova"is-there-a-difference-between-phone gap-and-cordovan-commands?Which command i need to use to create phonegap application?
Please any one can help me?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `phonegap` you will have to use phonegap commands.

While they are similar things they are not the same.

Read [this](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)
 blog post.

You will find that the commands are similar though (if not the same).

Phonegap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. It can have different features in the future. (Actually it already has cloud supporting feature.)